# Can we question about topic in Quran? I mean publicly scholars would say Islam is all about questions bt when we ask they say accept what is written

Tags: sharia, islamic-basis, ahlul-hadeeth

For eg
Beating of wives is not acceptable..but when i question it they would give me answers unacceptable.
Similarly women not allowed to marry non muslim men when we question it they say accept what it is written
Lastly, of marrying slave women there are no slavery system now so was that verse for that period.who decides that?
If that verse was for that period why can other verses be not for a period?

Comment: Yes, you can ask questions about Islam and what's in the Quran. Even the Sahaba have done so to the Prophet. What many Ulema say is there r some concepts that may not be in our grasp due to lack of knowledge or Iman and that we have to accept what is in the Quran. For eg the Quran is quite accurate in it's description of the stages of an embryo but it is highly unlikely humans 1400+ ago understood the concept like we do today due to advances in medical science There are many instances where all the 3 questions you pointed out above have been asked. Please use the search option on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of questioning.

Firstly, one can question the veracity (truthfulness) of a claim seeking evidence. Did God forbid women from marrying non-Muslim men? He did, and there is much evidence that can be presented. This is the allowed type of questioning, but it is necessary for people to accept the truth after the evidence is presented.

Secondly, one can question something other than the veracity. In modern times, this has usually manifested itself in questioning the ethics of something in light of liberal values.

An example would be: Liberal values indicate that men and women are equal, so anyone who treats them unequally is bad. Islam treats them unequally. How is this acceptable?

This is a type of questioning that is useless and forbidden. It presupposes baseless things (men and women should be treated equally; Why should they be? According to whom?), then questions Islam based on that.

It is not interested in the truth of whether God did command something. It is more interested in trying to force God to command something that conforms to this person's desires.

When scholars say Islam accepts questions, they are talking about the first. Islam accepts and welcomes questions about evidence. How do we know Islam is from God? How do we know this or that command is commanded by God?

No one cares about questions that are not about evidence. Why doesn't Islam treat men and women equally? This is a useless question. Why should it treat them equally in the first place? Because feminism is the flavor of today?

---

> Lastly, of marrying slave women there are no slavery system now so was that verse for that period

The verse is still applicable today even if slaves don't exist right now. If slaves began to exist in the future, it would apply.

The prerequisites for a command to come into play not existing is not the same as the command not existing.

For someone to have a concubine from slaves, slavery needs to exist. But, the concept of having concubines does not cease to exist just because slavery currently does not exist.

I will give an example: Imagine that pork no longer exists in a country. Would it be proper to say the prohibition of pork no longer exists? It wouldn't be proper.

> If that verse was for that period why can other verses be not for a period

The verse was not for any time period. It is for all times. If slavery existed right now, the rules of slavery would still apply. Just like that, the rules of marriage apply as long as marriage exists. We do not limit any rules to a certain time period.